# Magento 2, add `company's name` in invoice PDF file?

Tags: orders, magento2.2, invoice, pdf

Using `Magento 2.2`, `Invoice`, `PDF`. I want to **add** new text block into pdf invoice. What do I need to do?

> Printed Order Invoice
>   [image]

Comment: Hi @Bong here is your solution.

Comment: @ManishGoswami You dont need to comment that you posted an answer for the OP to see your answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Override AbstractPdf.php

> vendor\magento\module-sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf.php

Go To Line number 397 (protected function insertOrder(&$page, $obj, $putOrderId = true)) & after put this code

```
$this->_setFontBold($page, 15);
$companyName = "Company's name: ABCD";
$page->drawText($companyName, 350, $top - 20, 'UTF-8');
$this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
```

Your code look like

```
$page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(1));
$this->setDocHeaderCoordinates([25, $top, 570, $top - 55]);
$this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);  

/* Add company name code start here */
$this->_setFontBold($page, 15);
$companyName = "Company's name: ABCD";
$page->drawText($companyName, 350, $top - 20, 'UTF-8');
$this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
/* Add company name code End here */  

if ($putOrderId) {
            $page->drawText(__('Order # ') . $order->getRealOrderId(), 35, $top -= 30, 'UTF-8');

            $top +=15;
        }
```

[image]

I hope it will work for you

Answer (score 1):

Override the below file to your custom module:

> vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php

And update the function **getPdf** like below:

```
public function getPdf($invoices = [])
{
    $this->_beforeGetPdf();
    $this->_initRenderer('invoice');

    $pdf = new \Zend_Pdf();
    $this->_setPdf($pdf);
    $style = new \Zend_Pdf_Style();
    $this->_setFontBold($style, 10);

    foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
        if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
            $this->_localeResolver->emulate($invoice->getStoreId());
            $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore($invoice->getStoreId());
        }
        $page = $this->newPage();
        $order = $invoice->getOrder();
        /* Add image */
        $this->insertLogo($page, $invoice->getStore());
        /* Add address */
        $this->insertAddress($page, $invoice->getStore());
        /* Add head */
        $this->insertOrder(
            $page,
            $order,
            $this->_scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
                self::XML_PATH_SALES_PDF_INVOICE_PUT_ORDER_ID,
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                $order->getStoreId()
            )
        );
        /* Add document text and number */
        $this->insertDocumentNumber($page, __('Invoice # ') . $invoice->getIncrementId());

        // Add Company Name to Invoice PDF
        $docHeader = $this->getDocHeaderCoordinates();
        $page->drawText('Company\'s name: ABCD', 450, $docHeader[1]-15, 'UTF-8');

        /* Add table */
        $this->_drawHeader($page);
        /* Add body */
        foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item) {
            if ($item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) {
                continue;
            }
            /* Draw item */
            $this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order);
            $page = end($pdf->pages);
        }
        /* Add totals */
        $this->insertTotals($page, $invoice);
        if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
            $this->_localeResolver->revert();
        }
    }
    $this->_afterGetPdf();
    return $pdf;
}
```

You need to modify the 450 value according to your requirement if company name text is larger or smaller.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code to archive this task

```
app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml/di.xml
```

And overwrite invoice..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/*
 * Copyright © 2016 Rocket Bazaar. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" type="Namespace\ModuleName\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" />
</config>
```

Create New File

```
app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php
```

Use this code:-

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Namespace\ModuleName\Model\Order\Pdf;

/**
 * Sales Order Invoice PDF model
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Invoice extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice
{
    /**
     * @var \RB\Vendor\Helper\Data
     */
    private $vendorHelper;
    /**
     * @var \RB\Vendor\Model\VendorFactory
     */
    private $vendorFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Config $pdfConfig,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\Factory $pdfTotalFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\ItemsFactory $pdfItemsFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface $localeResolver,
        \RB\Vendor\Model\VendorFactory $vendorFactory,
        \RB\Vendor\Helper\Data $vendorHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($paymentData, $string, $scopeConfig, $filesystem, $pdfConfig, $pdfTotalFactory,
            $pdfItemsFactory, $localeDate, $inlineTranslation, $addressRenderer, $storeManager, $localeResolver, $data);
        $this->vendorHelper = $vendorHelper;
        $this->vendorFactory = $vendorFactory->create();
    }

    public function getPdf($invoices = [])
    {
        $this->_beforeGetPdf();
        $this->_initRenderer('invoice');

        $pdf = new \Zend_Pdf();
        $this->_setPdf($pdf);
        $style = new \Zend_Pdf_Style();
        $this->_setFontBold($style, 10);

        foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
            if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
                $this->_localeResolver->emulate($invoice->getStoreId());
                $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore($invoice->getStoreId());
            }
            $page = $this->newPage();
            $order = $invoice->getOrder();
            /* Add image */
            $this->insertLogo($page, $invoice->getStore());
            /* Add address */
            //$this->insertVendorAddress($page, $invoice->getStore(), $invoice->getVendorId());
            /* Add head */
            $this->insertOrder(
                $page,
                $order,
                $this->_scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
                    self::XML_PATH_SALES_PDF_INVOICE_PUT_ORDER_ID,
                    \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    $order->getStoreId()
                )
            );
            /* Add document text and number */
            $this->insertDocumentNumber($page, __('Invoice # ') . $invoice->getIncrementId());

            $vendor = $this->getVendorDetail($invoice->getVendorId());
            if(!empty($vendor)){
                    if(!empty($vendor->getBusinessName())) {
                        $vendorName = $vendor->getBusinessName();
                    }else { $vendorName = $vendor->getDisplayName(); }
                $this->insertVendorName($page, __('Company Name : ') .$vendorName);
                $this->insertVendorAddress($page, __('Company Address : ') .$this->getFullAddress($invoice->getVendorId()));
                $this->insertVendorVat($page, __('VAT : ') .$vendor->getVat());

                if(!empty($this->getVendorGstin($invoice->getVendorId()))) {
                    $this->insertVendorGstin($page, __('GSTIN : ') . $this->getVendorGstin($invoice->getVendorId()));
                }
            }


            /* Add table */
            $this->_drawHeader($page);
            /* Add body */
            foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item) {
                if ($item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }
                /* Draw item */
                $this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order);
                $page = end($pdf->pages);
            }
            /* Add totals */
            $this->insertTotals($page, $invoice);
            if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
                $this->_localeResolver->revert();
            }
        }
        $this->_afterGetPdf();
        return $pdf;
    }

    public function getVendorGstin($vendorId)
    {
        $vendor = $this->getVendorDetail($vendorId);
        if ($this->vendorHelper->isModuleEnabled('RB_VendorInd') && $this->vendorHelper->getConfigValue('rbvendorind/general_settings/enabled')) {
            if (!empty($vendor)) {
                return $vendor->getGstin();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $vendorId
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getVendorDetail($vendorId)
    {
        /* $vendorId = $this->orderItem->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('order_id',$this->getOrder()->getId())->getFirstItem()->getVendorId();*/
        $vendor = $this->vendorFactory->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('vendor_id', $vendorId)->getFirstItem();
        return $vendor;
    }

    public function getFullAddress($vendorId)
    {
        $vendor = $this->getVendorDetail($vendorId);
        if (!empty($vendor)) {
            return $vendor->getAddress1() . ' ' . $vendor->getAddress2() . ' ' . $vendor->getCity() . ' ' . $vendor->getRegion() . ' ' . $vendor->getPincode();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Insert title and number for concrete document type
     *
     * @param  \Zend_Pdf_Page $page
     * @param  string $text
     * @return void
     */
    public function insertVendorName(\Zend_Pdf_Page $page, $text)
    {
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(1));
        $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
        $docHeader = $this->getDocHeaderCoordinates();
        $page->drawText($text, 220, $docHeader[1] - 15, 'UTF-8');
    }

    /**
     * @param \Zend_Pdf_Page $page
     * @param $text
     */
    public function insertVendorAddress(\Zend_Pdf_Page $page, $text)
    {
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(1));
        $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
        $docHeader = $this->getDocHeaderCoordinates();
        $page->drawText($text, 220, $docHeader[1] - 30, 'UTF-8');
    }

    /**
     * @param \Zend_Pdf_Page $page
     * @param $text
     */
    public function insertVendorVat(\Zend_Pdf_Page $page, $text)
    {
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(1));
        $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
        $docHeader = $this->getDocHeaderCoordinates();
        $page->drawText($text, 220, $docHeader[1] - 45, 'UTF-8');
    }

    /**
     * @param \Zend_Pdf_Page $page
     * @param $text
     */
    public function insertVendorGstin(\Zend_Pdf_Page $page, $text)
    {
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(1));
        $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
        $docHeader = $this->getDocHeaderCoordinates();
        $page->drawText($text, 220, $docHeader[1] - 60, 'UTF-8');
    }
}
```

Comment: Class RB\Vendor\Model\VendorFactory does not exist what i put instead of RB as i am using default magento theme

Comment: Did you get the answer !

Comment: No. keep this task on hold.. Didn't get any solution.

Comment: Here you will add your custom module detail instead of vendor.
The class where you will get all the details.

Comment: I've created Satish_Invoice Module

Comment: I've created Satish_Invoice Module, inside etc folder - di.xml and module.xml than in Model folder - Order/Pdf/Invoice.php than registration.php and composer.json. is any other files need to add.

Answer (score 1):

There is much easier (no coding) way to do that (almost):

1. Go to:
   `Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales -> Invoice and Packing Slip Design`
2. Add your Company name (and address if needed) to **Address** field.

Result:
[image]